# Running class from JAR with multiple JAR dependencies via command prompt

Tags: java, jar, cmd, openjpa

I cannot understand why none of these are working. I've seen similar situations on stackoverflow and their solutions haven't worked for me.

I have a lib directory containing 15 JARs. When I run this command in command prompt from within that lib directory:

`java -cp openjpa-2.2.1.jar org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PCEnhancer`

I get a `NoClassDefFoundError` for one of it's dependencies.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: serp/bytecode/Instruction
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: serp.bytecode.Instruction
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
```

Now when I try to add the jar containing that dependency:

`java -cp openjpa-2.2.1.jar:serp-1.13.1.jar org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PCEnhancer`

I get this:

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PCEnhancer

I've also tried:

`java -cp openjpa-2.2.1.jar:serp-1.13.1.jar:. org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PCEnhancer`

`java -cp . org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PCEnhancer`

With the same effect, and when I try:

`java -cp serp-1.13.1.jar -jar openjpa-2.2.1.jar org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PCEnhancer [path to .java file]`

All I get is:

```
>OpenJPA 2.2.1
>version id: openjpa-2.2.1-r422266:1396819
>Apache svn revision: 422266:1396819

>os.name: Windows 7
>os.version: 6.1
>os.arch: amd64

>java.version: 1.8.0_25
>java.vendor: Oracle Corporation

>java.class.path:
>        openjpa-2.2.1.jar
```

With no file output, even when I add the -d flag with a directory.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try separating the jars in the classpath with `;` if you're on Windows.

Comment: Since java 1.5 (I think) you can add all of the JARs under `lib` to the classpath by doing `java -cp ./lib/* <Main Class>`

Comment: Thanks, @RealSkeptic I had tried semicolons before but I copied my previous command with colons from powershell and pasted it into Notepad++ to do a find/replace. Unfortunately, copy/pasting included newline characters that I hadn't noticed and broke the command. I thought it was because of the semi-colons.

Answer (score 0):

RealSkeptic's comment was correct. Semicolons are the proper syntax to separate JARs listed on the classpath in Windows, like so:

`java -cp jar1;jar2;jar3 classToRun args`